# proxy server refusing connection with only google.com and microsoft.com

Tags: proxy, http, navigation

Smartproxy is a paid HTTP proxy that provides residential ips where you pay 75$ for 5 gb of traffic for the micro plan which I'm using right now

when I connect via this proxy and try to visit google or microsoft websites I get this error:

> An error occurred during a connection to [www.microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com).
>
> - Check the proxy settings to make sure that they are correct.
> - Contact your network administrator to make sure the proxy server is working.

that or no response.
any other website I'm able to visite. I can login in my office account via office.com portal.
I can visit youtube.com  which is owned by google.
I tested my proxy with ubuntu and windows, I used mozilla firefox and google-chrome and Gologin and I get the same error everywhere.

my main question is why I can't visit only microsoft or google main websites?

Comment: Since you're paying for it, sounds like a question for [Smartproxy Support](https://smartproxy.com/questions/how-can-i-get-help-and-support).  Do you also have the [Smartproxy Chrome](https://help.smartproxy.com/docs/smartproxy-chrome-extension-1) and [Firefox extension](https://help.smartproxy.com/docs/smartproxy-firefox-extension-1) installed?

Answer (score -1):

This is because Smartproxy has blocked your account to use google owned websites. You need to write an email to risk@smartproxy.com and request for an unblock.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).